# How to include only specific properties of navigation property into the query by entity framework when lazy loading disabled?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

LazyLoading is disabled on my project. I want to get Product which is Id = 1 with Category navigation property of it. But I need just Id and Name properties of Category. That's why I want Category navigation property to has only these two fields.Is it possible to create such a query ?

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public dobule Price{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }       
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }   
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }      

    public int CategoryId{ get; set; }
    public Category Category{ get; set; }  
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public dobule Description{ get; set; }
    public Category IsDeleted { get; set; }       
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }   
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to only have these few values in your Category property? It won't make that much difference in performance.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want a few specific fields you will need to select them explicitly. Something like this would work:

```
dbContext.Products
    .Select(p => new Product
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        // etc... The fields you need from product go here
        Category = new Category
        {
            Id = p.Category.Id,
            Name = p.Category.Name
        }
    }
```

It might be better to have a Product and Category model class that only has the two fields. Now your method would return a Category object that lacks values for most fields which the caller might not expect. Depends on what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you know what do you want before calling the DB.

1. If you know what do you know, then you can use some 'Include' logic or the [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54503643/9031787) from @Sangman or check docu [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).
2. If you already have the entity in the memory and then you decide to load additional navigation property.

```
context.Entry(yourEntity).Reference(a => a.Category).Load();
```

More examples [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx).